# How do I escape a single quote in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I am passing some JSON to a server via a script (not mine) that accepts the JSON as a string.

Some of the content of the JSON contains single quotes so I want to ensure that any single quotes are escaped before being passed to the script.

I have tried the following:

```
> irb
> 1.9.3p194 :001 > x = "that's an awesome string"
>  => "that's an awesome string" 
> 1.9.3p194 :002 > x.sub("'", "\'")
>  => "that's an awesome string" 
> 1.9.3p194 :003 > x.sub("'", "\\'")
>  => "thats an awesome strings an awesome string"
```

but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: How are the values "passed"? Because *that* sounds like the flaw; JSON handles embedded quotes just fine, and once it is *inside* a Ruby string, it doesn't matter.

Comment: If "via script" means sub-process, then please open it *without* creating a subshell which will fix this issue entirely in Unix-like systems. (I am not sure if the Win32 stuff is sufficiently patched for this nonsense.)

Comment: `x.sub("'", "\\\\'")` does what you are trying to do. But the Tin Man's way is the right way to jsonify.

Comment: I was using the JSON gem but for some reaosn it won't run on client's machine and since he is providing the JSON in a massive text file with one record per line, and all my script needs to do is shove each line up to a server via a third-party script, so we nixed the need for the JSON gem and it mostly works apart from the unescaped quotes.

Comment: Zabb'a way doesn't work either FYI.  Get "that\\'s an awesome string"

Comment: If Ruby, Python, Perl, Java, PHP or any of many other languages, will run, then they can run a JSON interpreter and parse the strings received. Escaping single-quotes isn't the issue, it's why can't they run a JSON parser? See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) for a long list of languages that support JSON.

Comment: @DaveSag Then, why did you write JSON in the question? If you want people to focus on the string, why didn't you do that in the question? Why ask people not to do what you misguided them to do?

Answer (score 42):

The reason `sub("'", "\'")` does not work is because `"\'"` is the same as `"'"`. Within double quotes, escaping of a single quote is optional.

The reason `sub("'", "\\'")` does not work is because `"\\'"` expands to a backslash followed by a single quote. Within `sub` or `gsub` argument, a backslash followed by some characters have special meaning comparable to the corresponding global variable. Particularly in this case, the global variable `$'` holds the substring after the last matching point. Your `"\\'"` within `sub` or `gsub` argument position refers to a similar thing. In order to avoid this special convention, you should put the replacement string in a block instead of an argument, and since you want to match not just one, you should use `gsub` instead of `sub`:

```
gsub("'"){"\\'"}
```

Comment: No - that gives `"that\\'s an awesome string"`

Comment: @DaveSag That is a backslash followed by a single quote. How are you going to express a backslash followed by a single quote within double quotes without escaping the backslash? Let me know. Don't say you want `"\'"`, which is equivalent to `"'"`.

Comment: Best answer I've seen.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using the JSON gem?

```
require 'json'
some_object = {'a string' => "this isn't escaped because JSON handles it.", 'b' => 2}

puts some_object.to_json
=> {"a string":"this isn't escaped because JSON handles it.","b":2}
```

And a round-trip example:

```
require 'pp'
pp JSON[some_object.to_json]
=> {
    "a string" => "this isn't escaped because JSON handles it.",
        "b" => 2
}
```

And an example with double-quotes:

```
some_object = {
  'a string'       => "this isn't escaped because JSON handles it.",
  'another string' => 'double-quotes get "escaped"'
}
puts some_object.to_json
=> {
            "a string" => "this isn't escaped because JSON handles it.",
      "another string" => "double-quotes get \"escaped\""
  }
```

Comment: Not using the JSON gem because its not actually needed and its not running on my clients computer.

Comment: Been 8 years but this other comment is still so fresh

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that if you are trying to escape a single quote (apostrophe), you want to also escape double quotes. (This would apply for Javascript/JSON)

The easiest way is to use `escape_javascript` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html it "Escapes carriage returns and single and double quotes for JavaScript segments."

NOTE this works only for **Ruby on Rails**, not plain Ruby. However you can make a polyfill for plain Ruby using something like this:

```
JS_ESCAPE_MAP   =   { '\\' => '\\\\', '</' => '<\/', "\r\n" => '\n', "\n" => '\n', "\r" => '\n', '"' => '\\"', "'" => "\\'" }

def escape_javascript(javascript)
  if javascript
    result = javascript.gsub(/(\|<\/|\r\n|\342\200\250|\342\200\251|[\n\r"'])/u) {|match| JS_ESCAPE_MAP[match] }
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this way, use backslash to escape:

```
puts 'sean\'s'
```

output should be:

```
sean's
```