# Rails 4, single mass insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to optimize my rake task's performance by using a single mass insert instead of multiple calls to ActiveRecord's `create` method to import data.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
inserts = []
orders.each do |ord|
  inserts.push "('#{ord.company}', '#{ord.number}', '#{ord.line}', '#{Time.now.to_s(:db)}', '#{ord.comment}')"
end
sql = "INSERT INTO orders (company, number, line, created_at, comment) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

The problem is that the `comment` strings can contain the `'` character, so the generated sql query string would look like:

> INSERT INTO orders (company, number, line, created_at, comment) VALUES
>   ('100', '023074', '001', '2016-07-05 11:17:38', 'TRANSFORMATION K7'),
>   ('100', '023943', '001', '2016-07-05 11:17:38', 'BANDE PE D'AMARRAGE')

This will generate a

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AMARRAGE"

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` method:

```
inserts = []
orders.each do |ord|
  company = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(ord.company)
  number = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(ord.number)
  line = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(ord.line)
  comment = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(ord.comment)
  inserts.push "(#{company}, #{number}, #{line}, '#{Time.now.to_s(:db)}', #{comment})"
end
sql = "INSERT INTO orders (company, number, line, created_at, comment) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your string quotes are closing the string value in the SQL query. Try [escaping them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700218/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-ruby):

```
'#{ord.comment.gsub("'"){ "\\'" }'
```

This way, the SQL query will contain valid strings.

Also, you shouldn't do what you're trying to do. If the `comment` attribute contains sql code, may be injected, and do nasty stuff to your database. Please, read [this](http://rails-sqli.org/). Be safe!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

```
Order.sanitize(ord.comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Postgresql** the escape character is `single quote`. So if you want to mass insert into the database using `connection.execute` method, then replace the `single quote` with `two single quotes`

Here is the code example.

```
inserts = []
orders.each do |ord|
  inserts.push "('#{ord.company}', '#{ord.number}', '#{ord.line}', '#{Time.now.to_s(:db)}', '" + ord.comment.gsub("'","''")   + "')"
end
sql = "INSERT INTO orders (company, number, line, created_at, comment) VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```